# How to connecting to MySQL Server using MySQL.Data.CF from windows mobile

Tags: mysql, windows-mobile

I have a small application that runs on a DataLoxxxgic PDA Scanner on Windows Mobile 6.5. My application scans serials numbers and then uploads them to a MySQL Database.
I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 and MySQL.Data.CF ver. 6.7.4.0.

2 days ago I could connect perfectly and insert records to MySQL Database no problems. Since yesterday I keep on getting a Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL Hosts.

I want to mention that there is;
1) NO Firewall blocking
2) I have tried older versions of MySQLData.CF.
3) Check the MySQL Database as all info supplied is correct.

connections string as follows:

```
    Imports System.Data
    Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

    Dim cnnMySQL_Main As MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection
    Dim sConnectionString As String

    sConnectionString = "Server=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;"
    sConnectionString = sConnectionString & "Uid=xxxxx;"
    sConnectionString = sConnectionString & "Pwd=xxxxxx;"
    sConnectionString = sConnectionString & "Database=xxxxx;"
    sConnectionString = sConnectionString & "default command timeout=20;"
    sConnectionString = sConnectionString & "Allow Zero Datetime=true"



    'sConnectionString = String.Format("port=3306;server={0};user id={1}; password={2}; database=xxxxxxx; pooling=false", "server=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx", "xxxxxxx", "xxxxxx")

    cnnMySQL_Main = New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection(sConnectionString)


    Try


        If cnnMySQL_Main.State = Data.ConnectionState.Closed Then
            cnnMySQL_Main.Open()
            ConnectMySQLDB_main = True
        Else
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Connection Error :  " & ex.Message)
        ConnectMySQLDB_main = False
    Finally
        'ConnectMySQLDB_main = True
    End Try
```

I have tried various options but no luck.

Can anyone assist?

Thanks

Comment: Something has changed and your app does not woork any more. Try to run your code or a MySQL connection to the server to see if the server is working. Can you ping the server from the device, possobly the infrastructure has changed. How do you connect to the LAN? Same subnet as server? Routing correct?

Comment: Thanks for the information and advise. I  can ping the server. I can even connect to teh server via SQLYog and MySQL Workbench from SAME computer. Infrastructure has not changed.

Comment: Please double check your connection string. Did you use the same user etc in MySQL Workbench to connect? Testing diffeerent MySQL CF versions may have corrupted your installation. Check if the DLLs match and are of the same install.

Comment: Hi All. I fixed the issue. rather straight forward. I had the USB Cable plugged in with Active Synch running. The second that I unplugged this cable I could connect perfectly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue. rather straight forward. I had the USB Cable plugged in with Active Synch running. The second that I unplugged this cable I could connect perfectly!